# how to remove last 0 from values in row

Tags: r

I have one data frame which looks like this in that one column looks like this :-

col1

0.100

0.200

0.300

0.400

0.500

now I want to remove last zero from row. how I can do that any idea?

desired output.

col1

0.10

0.20

0.30

and so on!

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your column is of class character? In that case, you can use a pattern replacement. This will take care of removing the last zero all your values.

```
data <- data.frame(digit = c("0.100", "0.200", "0.300", "0.400", "0.500"))
data$digit <- gsub("0$", "", data$digit)
```

Comment: ohh i will try but i have it as numeric